# How to request and play IVONA Speech Cloud speech with AJAX

Tags: ajax, caching, text-to-speech

I am developing a language learning application, and want to use IVONA Speech Cloud to let users hear the pronunciation of words and phrases at the click of a button.

I suppose I have to request the sound data from the IVONA API with an AJAX call, but I have little experience with AJAX and APIs and I am unsure about how to progress.

IVONA API reference:
http://developer.ivona.com/en/speechcloud/api_ref_actions.html

Also, JQuery's documentation tells me that POST requests do not get cached, which makes me worry about caching. Do I need to implement my own cache then, to make sure the same users don't spend lots of bandwidth listening to the same sound clip again and again?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some sort of backend server (e.g. javascript, java, python, ruby, php etc) as you need to authenticate with the API using your Ivona credentials (which you get when you sign up). To my knowledge there is no way to keep these secret without proxying your requests through a server of some sort.